# How exactly CloudFront verifies certificates when connecting to origin servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I need some clarification about how CloudFront is connecting to the origin server via HTTPS.

From AWS website:

> When CloudFront uses HTTPS to communicate with your origin, CloudFront verifies that the certificate was issued by a trusted certificate authority. CloudFront supports the same certificate authorities as Mozilla; for the current list, see Mozilla Included CA Certificate List. You can't use a self-signed certificate for HTTPS communication between CloudFront and your origin.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html

I'm using a certificate issued by Let's Encrypt. The certificate is obtained when my origin server is attached to my domain. However, CloudFront is connecting to my origin via IP address. So, what exactly CloudFront does here? It only verifies that the certificate is issued by trusted CA? What's the point?  And by the way, what's the point in using HTTPS to connect to the origin when the server is actually an EC2 instance on AWS?

Comment: I completely agree with you. Maybe there is a reason for this, but such "reasoning" is not provided in the docs. If HTTP is allowed, then why not allow self-signed certificate? Why would I buy a Trusted CA certificate for a domain name like ec2-that-elastic-ip.amazonaws.com ? That's not even the name of the domain that I own! Maybe the reason is "self-signed HTTPS is as bad as HTTP"

Comment: Actually.... "HTTPS using self-signed certificate" would be secure if AWS CF allows us to upload a copy of the certificate to CF, so that CF can check the one we uploaded in AWS console vs the one returned by the origin!! As long as the client "knows" the certificate, self-signed is fairly good.

Comment: BTW.. does this mean I can use my "real domain name" certificate on EC2 and expose it as "ec2-elastic-ip" and AWS CF would still go ahead and accept the certificate?

Comment: Oops.. AWS docs explain how the validation is done. Perfect! "CloudFront uses the Host header value instead if you configure it to forward the Host header, which means that the origin’s TLS certificate must contain www.example.com in its CN or SAN. CloudFront also uses those domain names as an SNI in its initial TLS handshake. "

Comment: Cloudfare provides free "origin" certificate.. which is almost like self-signed and uploaded to receiver.

Answer (score 4):

> *So, what exactly CloudFront does here? It only verifies that the certificate is issued by trusted CA?*

An SSL certificate serves two purposes:

- providing a public key for initializing the encryption
- authenticating the fact that the server at `www.example.com` is indeed authorized to serve `www.example.com`.

SSL certs form a chain of trust back to a trusted root certificate, each of them signed by a higher level of trust.  CloudFront is verifying that the certificate is *genuinely* signed by an issue that is traceable up to a known trusted root.

And, CloudFront is verifying that the certificate is valid for the host in question.

> When CloudFront uses HTTPS to communicate with your origin, CloudFront verifies that the certificate was issued by a trusted certificate authority. CloudFront supports the same certificate authorities as Mozilla; for the current list, see [Mozilla Included CA Certificate List](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/included/). You can't use a self-signed certificate for HTTPS communication between CloudFront and your origin.
>
> **Important**
>
> If the origin server returns an expired certificate, an invalid certificate, or a self-signed certificate, or if the origin server returns the certificate chain in the wrong order, CloudFront drops the TCP connection, returns HTTP status code 502 (Bad Gateway), and sets the X-Cache header to Error from cloudfront.
>
> Also, if the full chain of certificates, including the intermediate certificate, is not present, CloudFront drops the TCP connection.
>
> One of the domain names in the certificate must match one or both of the following values:
>
> - The value that you specified for Origin Domain Name for the applicable origin in your distribution.
> - If you configured CloudFront to forward the Host header to your origin, the value of the Host header. For more information about forwarding headers to your origin, see Configuring CloudFront to Cache Objects Based on Request Headers.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html

> *What's the point?*

That's how SSL (TLS) works.  The browser does the same thing when it connects to a server with SSL -- it verifies that the certificate is valid and matches the site you *think* you connected to.

Without this constraint, you're disabling and throwing away one of two components provided by SSL -- authentication of the server.

> *what's the point in using HTTPS to connect to the origin when the server is actually an EC2 instance on AWS?*

The point is that, yes, if the origin server is in EC2, it's a more secure environment than over the public Internet, because the traffic is only on the Amazon network... but being on the Amazon network does not provide total immunity to compromise or interception.  It's highly unlikely, but not technically impossible.  This falls under the area of "best practices."  Using SSL here means that intercepted traffic -- if it occurred -- would still not be useful to the malicious entity doing the interception.

But also, CloudFront works perfectly well with origin servers that are **not** in EC2, so traffic from CloudFront to the origin traverses the public Internet.

There's no rule that requires you to use SSL on your origin server, even if CloudFront us proving HTTPS connectivity between it and the browser.  It's technically possible to configure the Origin Protocol Policy for HTTP-Only... but, again, it's not a best practice.

Comment: _CloudFront is verifying that the certificate is valid for the host in question_ -
From where it gets the host? `Host` header? (I'm pointing CloudFront to my origin using IP address)

Comment: _There's no rule that requires you to use SSL on your origin server, even if CloudFront us proving HTTPS connectivity between it and the browser. It's technically possible to configure the Origin Protocol Policy for HTTP-Only... but, again, it's not a best practice._ How to do it ?